# BrowserStack integration with TestCafe: How to fix "The specified screen resolution is not compatible with the chosen OS version"?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browserstack

I have configured the environment variables as follows: [image]

This resolution is supposed to be compatible with every OS, still tried many others and also different OS.
I applied the same settings for the .env file on the project.

Comment: What OS have you tried? I see that this resolution is the default one and when selected is not added to the selenium capabilities, it might be a bug from them. Give a try without adding the resolution capability and see what resolution it gets and after specify another combination from their `automate/capabilities`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the configurations you have provided to initiate your tests?

Since you have specified the flag `BROWSERSTACK_USE_AUTOMATE="1"`, the setting on https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities would come into effect.

Comment: Currently I launch the tests from command line. Aren't those capability settings only for Selenium based projects?